# Proper MOUSE_OVER event on empty frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Let's say I have a flash with a few empty frames (or frames that have rectangles in them from using the Rectangle Tool).

How do I properly attach the MOUSE_OVER listener so when my mouse is over ***any pixel of the flash, even when on those said empty frames***, the event fires?

### Edit

***For all you downvoters***, I want to clarify and remind you that

1. I am new to Flash, and asking others and going through documentation I found nothing on my question, and
2. I already tried `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handler);`, to no avail. Yes, I properly imported the packages, and the entire swf compiled without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse events only fire on objects that extend [`InteractiveObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html).

If you are drawing some simple [`Shape`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html#eventSummary) primitives, as in drawing with the rectangle tool, no mouse events will be dispatched.

> Shape Inheritance: DisplayObject » EventDispatcher » Object

Convert those to a symbol, changing inheritance to extend an interactive object such as [`MovieClip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html)

> MovieClip Inheritance: Sprite » DisplayObjectContainer » InteractiveObject » DisplayObject » EventDispatcher » Object

Then, you may attach an event listener to specific objects; or, simply adding a listener to the document root will fire events:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
```

If you need events fired from areas where there are no visual elements, one trick is to create a transparent movie clip simply to act as an interactive object on the display list.

Remove stroke and set your fill color to zero alpha.

[image: fill-color]

Then, draw a rectangle - it may appear as though nothing was added on the art board; however, when selected you see it exists.  Select all if you can't find it:

[image: selected]

You can then use that symbol with zero alpha by placing multiple instances on the stage.

Here, that symbol has been added to the stage with an instance name of "hitArea"

[image: hitArea]

You can now add events to that region specifically:

```
hitArea.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hitAreaOverHandler);
```

Repeat for as many regions needed, giving each a unique instance name.

Rarely is this practical; however, there are scenarios such as user controls, making larger hit areas than the original button, or when dealing with complex graphs of children on the display list by adding interaction on top and disabling all mouse events to children beneath.

Comment: I must not be understanding you properly. There was a rectangle on one frame, in which I right-clicked it, and clicked "Convert to symbol". I then proceeded to convert everything in my flash on all frames to symbols, but when I ran the code (with the modification from `stage`->`this`), it still didn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh, whoops, just noticed your edit. Will try it out.

Comment: Okay, I ended up changing all of the symbol types to "Movie Clip", and then modified the code to go back to "stage", and *that* seemed to work. It's good enough for what I'm doing anyway. But hey, thanks for answering my question. I really appreciate it.